# C sudoku backtracking solver precheck function

Tags: c, function, sudoku, backtracking

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so I apologize if I'm doing something wrong. I'm relatively new to C, so I'm sure my code is fairly ugly and hacky in places, however the majority of the code does what I expect it to. I'm having trouble with a `precheck` method that I'm using to check a sudoku board before I begin feeding it through my solver-logic. I'm redirecting input from a text file with strings that look like

> 4.....8.5.34.........7......2.....6.....8.4......1.......6.3.7.5..2.....1.4......
>   4.....8.5.3..........7......2.....6.....8.4......1.......6.3.7.5..2.....1.5......
>   4.....8.5.3..........7......2.....6.....8.4......1...x...6.3.7.5..2.....1.4......
>   417369825632158947958724316825437169791586432346912758289643571573291684164875293
>   417369825632158947958724316825437169791586432346912758289643.71573291684164875293

Each string is (ideally) 81 characters with just digits 1-9 and '.'s. I parse a string into a temp char array, and then use the method `fillBoard` to transfer the chars in the temp array into a 2d int array. Once this is complete, I call my `precheck` method. If the filled board doesn't pass the row, column, and box checks, the `precheck` method returns a one, indicating that the puzzle is not solvable (meaning an error message should be printed and that the program should move on to the next string). For some reason, my `precheck` method is returning one even for strings that should be solvable. I'm not sure why this is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int alphaError = 0;

struct Point findEmpty(int board[9][9]);
int usedInBox(int board[9][9], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num);
int positionSafe(int board[9][9], int row, int col, int num);
int usedInCol(int board[9][9], int col, int num);
int usedInRow(int board[9][9], int row, int num);
int solvePuzzle(int board[9][9]);
int precheck(int board[9][9]);

int main()
{
  char c;
  int charCount = 0;
  int i = 0;
  char tempStr[100000];
  int board[9][9];

  while((fscanf(stdin, "%c", &c)) != EOF)
  {
    printf("%c", c);

    if(c != '\n')
    {
      if(isalpha(c))
      {
        alphaError = 1;
      }

      tempStr[i] = c;
      i++;
      charCount++;
    }
    else
    {
      if(charCount != 81 || alphaError == 1)
      {
        printf("Error\n\n");
        i = 0;
        charCount = 0;
        alphaError = 0;
      }
      else 
      {
        fillBoard(board, tempStr);
        printBoard(board);
        if(precheck(board) == 1)
        {
          printf("Error\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
          if(solvePuzzle(board) == 1)
          {
            printBoard(board);
          }
          else
          {
            printf("No solution\n\n");
          }
        }
        i = 0;
        charCount = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

struct Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
} point;

struct Point findEmpty(int board[9][9])
{
  struct Point point1;
  point1.x = -1;
  point1.y = -1;
  int row, col;

  for(row = 0; row < 9; row++)
  {
    for(col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
      if(board[row][col] == 0)
      {
        point1.x = col;
        point1.y = row;
      }
    }
  }
  return point1;
}

int usedInBox(int board[9][9], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num)
{
  int row, col;

  for(row = 0; row < 3; row++)
  {
    for(col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
      if(board[row + boxStartRow][col + boxStartCol] == num)
      {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int positionSafe(int board[9][9], int row, int col, int num)
{
  if((usedInRow(board, row, num)) == 0 && (usedInCol(board, col, num)) == 0 && (usedInBox(board, (row-row%3), (col-col%3), num)) == 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

int usedInCol(int board[9][9], int col, int num)
{
    int row;

    for(row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
    if(board[row][col] == num)
     {
       return 1;
     }
  }
  return 0;
}


int usedInRow(int board[9][9], int row, int num)
{
  int col;

  for(col = 0; col < 9; col++)
  {
    if(board[row][col] == num)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int solvePuzzle(int board[9][9])
{
  int num;
  struct Point point2;

  point2 = findEmpty(board);
  if(point2.x == -1)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  for(num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
  {
    if(positionSafe(board, point2.y, point2.x, num) == 1)
    {
      board[point2.y][point2.x] = num;

      if(solvePuzzle(board) == 1)
      {
        return 1;
      }

      board[point2.y][point2.x] = 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void printBoard(int board[9][9]) 
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      printf("%d", board[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\n");
}  

void fillBoard(int board[9][9], char tempStr[100000])
{
  int i, j;
  int k = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
  {
    for(j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
    {
      if(tempStr[k] == '.')
      {
        board[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        board[i][j] = (tempStr[k] - '0');
      }
      k++;
    }
  }
}

int precheck(int board[9][9])
{
  int i, j, num;

  for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      if(board[i][j] != 0)
      {
        num = board[i][j];
        if(positionSafe(board, i, j, num) == 0)
        {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are using `precheck` on an already filled board? That might be the problem because `usedInCol`, `usedInRow` and `usedInBlock` will return 1 if the value is already present. So `precheck` should be used only while filling the board, not after. It will always return 1 if you check values you take from the already filled board.

Comment: Good catch! But he can check the board afterwards if he just ignores the [row, col] being investigated.

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't. And I think it is well implemented, but the `precheck` test only needs to be done in the filling function (for each value just before putting it in the `board` table).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I eventually realized that the precheck method was finding the same same value I was passing in, which is why it was always returning true. I just added an if check to account for this. But maybe I'll try and figure out a way to this before the board is actually filled. That certainly makes more sense.